# Auto Arranging data in GROUPBY with serial Number in existing table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have an existing table (Table A) which I want to be arranged in group wise per subject column and id to be arranged in ID column as per Table -B. And in future if i add any data it should also arranged in the same manner. Is it possible in Mysql? i tried to arrange the column bgroup wise but i am not able to generate the id
[image]

Comment: how is possible upvote a question like this ????

Comment: @scaisEdge What is wrong with question ?

Comment: you should add  the data sample as tabular text and not as image ( or link only as before the edit). and your question is not clear.. You want  the result ordered by subject of order by id  ??? (both  may be not always  possible ).. and also you should add  your actual code

Comment: @jigar Please don't use images if unnecessary - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @scaisEdge earlier I designed the data table like Table "A" .But now I want to edit the data like Table" B" with id changed grouped by subject. Is it possible please help me

Comment: "id" is meaningless in this context

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question as follows: you want to reassign `id`s within groups of records having the same `subject`, ordered by old `id`.

If you are running MySQL 8.0 (or Maria DB >= 10.2), you can do this with `row_number()`:

```
select
    row_number() over(partition by subject order by id) id,
    user,
    subject
from tableA
```

I would not recommend creating a new table for this (that you would need to maintain when data in the original table changes), instead you can use a view, that would compute the new `id`s on the fly:

```
create view ViewA as
select
    row_number() over(partition by subject order by id) id,
    user,
    subject
from tableA
```

Comment: I am using Server version: 10.4.8-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution

Comment: @jigar: `row_number()` is available starting MariaDB 10.2, you should be able to use it.